# Waiting for a page to load and then displaying it, without an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hey! Let's say I have a big application in one *.html* file. Another file, that should be pretty lightweight, is the "loader" page. The small file loads and then calls the big file while displaying something like "loading"...

I know I can use a hidden iFrame and unhide it on it's `onload` event. However, I don't like iFrames. So how could I do this without one? AJAX maybe? Any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Gives exactly what you are suggesting? With a little loading div on ajaxRequest and closing it on ajaxSucces.

Comment: I guess I'll use AJAX then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a container div with the css set to `display:none;` and then switch it to `display:block;` on the onload event.

Comment: Would the page render OK before it's fully loaded? Like would the "loading..." message or whatever display right even before the other "container" is done loading?

Comment: If you wanted a loading message you could have two divs positioned absolutely on top of one another. You would have the div containing the loading message with display:block; and the main page with display:none;. You would then switch the display values of both divs giving a seemless tranisition. Everything would still load fine it would just be invisible to the user; all your page would still load into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, although I decided to use AJAX.